# Why sometimes the SMS BroadcastReceiver is called twice?

Tags: android

I register a BroadcastReceiver for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`.

Sometimes the BroadcastReceiver `onReceive` is called twice on the same SMS.

Why is that?

what am I doing wrong?

```
private void initSmsReceivers() {
smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();
getActivity().registerReceiver(smsReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
}



public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                // str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                // str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

            }
            // ---display the new SMS message---
            String output = CryptoUtils.decrypt(str);
            Toast.makeText(context, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                parsemessage(output);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("JSON2", e.toString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered this receiver or called `initSmsReceivers()` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: how do you know that it is called twice ?

Comment: @Lisa Anne Have you fixed it ? I also facing the same issue now..

Answer (score 5):

I solved mine by filtering before doing action.. In my case the receiver was called twice because I have two intent filter 'SMS_DELIVER' and  'SMS_RECEIVED'.. See below for the example

In my manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String TAG = "SmsReceiver";
String sender, text;
private static final String ACTION_SMS_NEW = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // ---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            text += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            Log.i(TAG, sender + " sender\ntext " + text);
        }
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive(context, " + action + ")");
        if (ACTION_SMS_NEW.equals(action)) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", sender);
            values.put("body", text);
            context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);

            MiscMethods.delay(10);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

It could be the case that you are registering the broadcast receiver both **programatically**, and  **statically**. So make sure that `initSmsReceivers` is called exactly once, and that in your manifest you are not re-registering that receiver!

Here's how you statically register a receiver for sms in the manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="your.package.SmsReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I registered on both places, through statically and through the service, and resolved the problem by the starting the service when the activity is closed. Basically onDestroy method.

Answer (score 3):

In `onReceive()` filter intent action:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"){
       //handle received sms
}
else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"){
       //do something
}
```